Alternate history - Blondlot's N-Rays really exist, leading to French dominance in 20th century
Around 2005, I read in a "Best of the Year" anthology I think, a short piece (novella or shorter) in which Blondlot really did discover N-rays in the early 20th century, and the technological jump that this gave to France led to France dominating the world later in the century.  I thought the title mentioned Paris, but I may be wrong. The story is (if I recall correctly) mostly a tour of the mighty French realm.

This is Sisyphus and the Stranger by Paul di Fillipo.

What if: N-rays really existed, and France used them to gain a quick victory in the Great War.
Summary: In 1954 of a world dominated by France, the Algerian bureaucrat Albert Camus meets a mysterious traveler.

The story has been collected in a range of "Best Of" anthologies

Absolutely right.  I even saw that title in a listing, but didn't recognize it - but now I recognize it as a reference to Camus.  Thanks.

And I even checked uchronia - but searched for Blondot instead of n-rays
